Firefox - request queued, but no sending, waiting, or blocked?
How should I interpret this firefox network HAR trace?

It seems like the last request has just been dropped by the OS or something?
Normally I'd expect a timeout, or blocked or something.
Requests that get into this state seem to just hang forever. Refreshing the browser seems to fix the problem...
I'm developing a react app, using tanstack for graphql requests.
Some clients are experiencing problems like this...

I'm attempting to fix this issue for my Tan Stack Graphql useMutation hooks using a timeout.
Code looks like this:
const DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 10000;

export function withTimeout<T>(
  promise: Promise<T>,
  timeoutDuration: number = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
): Promise<T> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      reject(new Error('Request timed out'));
    }, timeoutDuration);

    promise
      .then(resolve)
      .catch(reject)
      .finally(() => clearTimeout(timer));
  });
}

This function is used like this:
    const loginWithTimeout = withTimeout(
      mutateAsync({
        username,
        password,
      })
    );
    const { token, error } = await loginWithTimeout;

A colleague suggested this approach to apply to the whole application
    new GQLClient(
      url,
      {
        credentials: 'include',
        fetch: async (input: RequestInfo, init?: globalThis.RequestInit) => {
          const controller = new AbortController();

          const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
            controller.abort();
          }, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);

          try {
            return await fetch(input, {
              ...init,
              signal: controller.signal,
            });
          } finally {
            clearTimeout(timerId);
          }
        },
      },
      skipRequest
    )

This doesn't provide a way to increase the timeout for slow operations though, so you'd want to make sure the timeout time is sufficiently long for all operations.
